# hybridauth JSON implemention for html 5 purposes

Tags: json, hybridauth

Does anyone know what needs to be done in order make hybridauth able to communication over JSON. I wanna implement this plugin for mobile (phonegap) purposes. But connecting with a server (php) is very limited when using a web-app. So JSON is the only option here.